# Making all possible combination of python lists

Tags: python, list, loops, combinations, sequence

I have looked into several lists combination threads, but none of them was related to what I intend to do here.

Having the following lists:

```
traveler = ["John", "Joseph", "Mary", "Anna"]
brazil_destinations = ["Sao Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Salvador", "Curitiba", "Porto Alegre", "Belo Horizonte"]
us_destinations = ["New York", "Orlando", "Miami", "Denver", "Houston", "Phoenix"]
italy_destinations = ["Rome", "Venice", "Florence"]
germany_destinations = ["Munich", "Berlin", "Bohn", "Bremen"]
```

I need a list of lists of all possible combinations (always picking one traveler and one city at each country). Desired output is:

```
[["John", "Sao Paulo", "New York", "Rome", "Munich"],
["John", "Sao Paulo", "New York", "Rome", "Berlin"],
["John", "Sao Paulo", "New York", "Rome", "Bohn"],
["John", "Sao Paulo", "New York", "Rome", "Bremen"],
["John", "Sao Paulo", "New York", "Venice", "Munich"],
["John", "Sao Paulo", "New York", "Venice", "Berlin"],
[...],
[...],
[...]]
```

Note 1: I need flexibility in the number of country lists. In this case there are 4 country lists (Brazil, US, Italy & Germany), but this may frequently change.

Note 2: It has to be something efficient, so a solution with recursive function might be the best fit. Unfortunately I couldn't manage to code it up.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youy can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

traveler = ["John", "Joseph", "Mary", "Anna"]
brazil_destinations = [
    "Sao Paulo",
    "Rio de Janeiro",
    "Salvador",
    "Curitiba",
    "Porto Alegre",
    "Belo Horizonte",
]
us_destinations = [
    "New York",
    "Orlando",
    "Miami",
    "Denver",
    "Houston",
    "Phoenix",
]
italy_destinations = ["Rome", "Venice", "Florence"]
germany_destinations = ["Munich", "Berlin", "Bohn", "Bremen"]

out = []
for c in product(
    traveler,
    brazil_destinations,
    us_destinations,
    italy_destinations,
    germany_destinations,
):
    out.append(list(c))

print(*out, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```py
['John', 'Sao Paulo', 'New York', 'Rome', 'Munich']
['John', 'Sao Paulo', 'New York', 'Rome', 'Berlin']
['John', 'Sao Paulo', 'New York', 'Rome', 'Bohn']
['John', 'Sao Paulo', 'New York', 'Rome', 'Bremen']
['John', 'Sao Paulo', 'New York', 'Venice', 'Munich']

...
```